# What does it mean to ask: "What is the probability of rolling a 7?"

Tags: probability-theory

When one asks what is the probability of rolling a 7 on a 6-sided die (labeled 1-6) what does that mean in measure theory? I cannot find an answer anywhere.

does it mean that P({7}) = P({}) = 0 and the event is impossible?

or does it mean that it is implausible because {7} is not in the sigma-algebra?

or does it mean that the question is ill-posed?

---

for reference:

If we take the probability space (,ℱ,),

An event ⊆ is impossible if =∅

An event ⊆ is implausible if ∉ℱ

An event ⊆ is improbable if *()=0

Comment: Phrased as an abstract math problem, You can't ask for the probability of an event not in the universe of events any more than you could ask for the sine of Thursday.  Of course you could extend the definition of the random variable (or the sine function) to include those arguments if you liked, but that would have to be done explicitly.

Comment: @lulu that is interesting because that's how I thought it, so the question is nonsensical. Thanks!

Comment: @lulu However, I have heard that the probability outside of the support should be 0? so P({7}) can be defined as 0 since it is outside of the support

Comment: "support" only makes sense once the universe of events has been specified.  I certainly agree that assigning any value to $P(7)$ *other* than $0$ would be very problematic, but I'd prefer to say it was simply not defined.

Comment: @user29418 I rest my case that it all depends on the model you want to choose. This has to come from *you*. I can only hope this is not a school assignment where your teacher has a preconception which model *should* be chosen, and would then mark your answer as "right" or "wrong" depending on whether your model matches theirs. For myself, I can engage in a bit of doublethink, in being able to imagine the probability to be ill-defined (in one model) and simultaneously being able to imagine that it is $0$ (in a different model).

Comment: In the discrete case this is simple : An event that cannot happen is an impossible event and has probability $0$. In fact, an event has probability $0$ iff it is impossible. Unfortunately, this does not hold in the continous case. Still, the impossible event has probability $0$ , but probability $0$ does not imply anymore that the event is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Previously was a comment, putting it as an answer as the OP seems to be happy with it.)

It means whatever you choose it to mean. The measure theory is used to model probabilities from the real world, but it is up to you, when solving the real-world problem, to set up the model (i.e. the probability space) so that it works. For example, you may choose that $X=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}, \mathcal F=\mathcal P(X)$ (in which case the question is ill-posed as $7\not\in X$), or you may choose that $X=\mathbb Z, \mathcal F=\mathcal P(\mathbb Z)$ (in which case the probability is $0$).

By the way, what you cannot say is that $\{7\}=\emptyset$. The set $\{7\}$ is not empty. Whether it belongs to $\mathcal F$ or not is another story.